# Need an app config file opinion here

Tags: xml, service, app-config

I know that app config is used to provide environmental type of values for process variables. And it is very much key/value oriented.

But I have a process (windows service) that uses a skeleton xml template file to produce a fuller version of that file after processesing.

What about the idea of including that 'skeleton xml' in the app config file?

I am trying to aviod having a standalone xml skeleton file, since it is 'configuration' related, in a way.

Answer (score 1):

It's straightforward to store XML in an application configuration setting if you've serialized it as XML text, e.g. to save it, assuming that `myXmlDocument` is an `XmlDocument`:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyXmlSkeleton = myXmlDocument.OuterXml;
```

and to retrieve it:

```
myXmlDocument.LoadXml(Properties.Settings.Default.MyXmlSkeleton);
```

But you won't readily to be able to change the XML by editing the configuration file, since it will be stored as XML text, e.g.:

```
value='&lt;MyXmlDocument/&gt;'
```

That's probably not a problem, because you're probably not going to want to edit the application configuration file to change the XML anyway - there's far too much risk of introducing well-formedness errors if you do that.

Generally, though, I find that this isn't the right approach; I'll either load the XML from the file system at runtime and store the path to the XML document in the configuration file, or I'll include the XML as a string resource.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can

- To create a [custom configuration section](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3617366/NET-Tip-Create-a-Custom-Configuration-Section-in-NET-20.htm) into .config file and work with its serialized version
- To store that XML directly at `appSettings`, encoded as string
- To define a file path at `appSettings` and, there, place your XML file

If you ask me, I would go with last option, since it's easier to maintain.

Comment: The 3rd option then being the standalone XML file, located via the app config file?

Comment: Yes Chris; that's easier to update and doesn't requires an app pool recycle